# why my page is not scrolling full at the bottom in selenium testNG(java)?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, testng, xpath

[image][image][image]The images below are my codes(Singleton,homepage and test classes) I'm new to automation and I tried to achieve POM using Singleton now my problem is whenever I try to run my test cases it navigates to the page but it doesn't scroll right at the bottom and click the clickable element, rather it scrolls down more than 60% and clicks the clikable element.